# can't regenerate bridge header for using swift in objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I updated a Swift library (updating .swift files and adding new .swift files to my project)but in doing so the old bridge header is not found, and Xcode 8.3.3. doesn't prompt to create a new one.

This article shows the window with the button "create bridging header": http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Any ideas?

My `#import "app-Swift.h"` isn't found after adding the new files.  Nor can I right click and go to definition.

Comment: you should move only .h and .m files not group or folder

Comment: you mean .swift?  The files being added or overwritten are .swift.  Are you saying there is some issue with deleting and re-adding the folder with .swift files?

Comment: yes, you should add only swift file, then you move those files in a group

Comment: why?  I think all I did was add/overwrite some existing .swift and added new .swift not touching the folders.  I'm going to double check

Comment: what you suggested did not make a difference.  Also, why would it?

Answer (score -1):

You can create `Bridging Header` manually.

1. Add new header file. Name it something meaningful as `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`
2. Select `Project -> Target -> Build Setting`
3. Search for `"bridging header"` in the search box
4. Double click the on `Objective-C Bridging Header` value portion
5. Drag and drop your manually created `ProjectName-Bridging-Header` file
6. Build your project

[Click to show a video tutorial](https://youtu.be/TlzuYqwTdOk)

Comment: I'm not importing Obj-C into swift I'm importing Swift into Obj-C.  I want the auto generated header with all the method signatures.  Just as it says in the Apple doc "When you import Swift code into Objective-C, you rely on an Xcode-generated header file to expose those files to Objective-C. This automatically generated file is an Objective-C header that declares the Swift interfaces in your target. It can be thought of as an umbrella header for your Swift code. "